# Bootstrap in only IE isn't loading jQuery - Slideshow won't work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I'm using bootstrap 3 as a base for my web project.  I can't understand why the JS functions all work on Chrome, Firefox, Android, iOS, etc. but not on IE?  The debug errors all hint that jQuery, or $ isn't defined, but I can't understand why the problem is specific to IE.  Everything works flawlessly on other platforms, and although I know bootstrap slideshows aren't made to be compatible with older versions of IE, it should be working on IE 11.

I've also tried working another slideshow in using http://bxslider.com/ 's slideshow.  Again, this works on everything besides IE.  The errors are the same, and seem to be related to jQuery not being loaded.

http://tinyurl.com/ox5uujl

Comment: I'm almost positive it has something to do with IE's strict comment parsing. http://postimg.org/image/5ewcnlc8j/ Fix the comments in the picture.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I've updated the comments with the same result.  Originally put those in there so I wouldn't get lost in this maze trying to debug.  Any other ideas?

Comment: you have a new error. check the console.

Comment: Thanks again.  I checked the console and commented some unnecessary code.  I'm getting no errors now, but the result is still the same.  Slideshow doesn't work, but only on IE.

Comment: is it working now? i can see you are making changes

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  I am still getting the same results, only without the errors.  I'm out of ideas at this point..  Any other suggestions?

Even more curious, I made a very basic test page which works fine with almost identical (watered down) code.

http://tinyurl.com/okofthw

Comment: You still have mark up errors. Open the page in firefox, view source and hover over everything that is red. Fix them all. You can skip the one on body, It won't resolve until you fix the others.

Comment: E.G <a href="articles.php?cat=Articles"><li>Articles</a>  you are missing the closing </li> in this line

Comment: Great point. I've removed all errors.  0 Errors now, but still same result?

Comment: It looks like the problem is your links inside the div.item. Remove them and see if it works.

Comment: She's fixed. I rebuilt the file and cleaned the code up. I never did specifically find an issue